# Why vector images behave weirdly with API < 24 Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-vectordrawable

I was trying to make a **custom vector image** for my android app, I figuered out a good pathData.

I'm using the `A` to create an arc/curve in the paths data, and got the correct result in the **Preview** window, also got the correct result when I ran the app in different phones.

but IDK why it outputs a straight line in production on phones with Android 6.0 (**API<23**)!

Here is the vector image XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportWidth="400"
    android:viewportHeight="200">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#0277BD"
        android:pathData="M0,200 L70,200 A130,130 0 0,1 118,99 L74,45 A200,200 0 0,0 0,200 Z"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="#000" />

    <path
        android:fillColor="#4CAF50"
        android:pathData="M74,45 L118,99 A130,130 0 0,1 200,70 L200,0 A200,200 0 0,0 74,45 Z"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="#000" />

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFC107"
        android:pathData="M200,0 L200,70 A130,130 0 0,1 265,87.4 L300,26.8 A200,200 0 0,0 200,0 Z"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="#000" />

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF5722"
        android:pathData="M300,26.8 L265,87.4 A130,130 0 0,1 312.6,135 L373.2,100 A200,200 0 0,0 300,26.8 Z"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="#000" />

    <path
        android:fillColor="#DB1C1C"
        android:pathData="M373.2,100 L312.6,135 A130,130 0 0,1 330,200 L400,200 A200,200 0 0,0 373.2,100 Z"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="#000" />

</vector>
```

Here is the Preview from Android Studio (and the wanted result)
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mTaO.png)

Here is the output on Android 6.0 phone
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXTnv.png)

Comment: It seems like your vector path don't have enough precision that's why its not drawing correctly, it happens mainly in api level below 24, If you have made that svg yourself, then add more precision and use this tool [SVGO](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) to compress it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have .svg file of picture, upload it in Android Studio by **clicking right** mouse button on **drawable folder** in Android Studio **Project** (Alt+1), choose **New** and **Vector Asset**. In **Asset Type** select **Local file (SVG, PSD)**, browse to your .svg file and let Android Studio convert it into .xml.

You'll give it name and then you can find it in **drawable folder** or call it by name in .java/.kt or in .xml layout file.

Hope it helps